# argument of animate method of jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know I have some problem with syntax. This javascript seems to have weird syntax as per my experience compared to python. Why is this code not working?

```
<script>
  function flutter() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    var $obj = $('.bird');
    $obj.animate({ top :'-= 0.5px'+random }, 20, flutter);

    } 
</script>
```

I know the way I have added random is the culprit but I don't know the right way.

Comment: You're adding to a string with letters in it...

Comment: Can you please write me a correct way?

Comment: @Ed Heal beat me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '+' is overloaded

Try

```
$obj.animate({ top :'-=' + (0.5+random) + 'px' }, 20, flutter);
```

Comment: I am adding for 5 additional minutes! Won't let me do it now!

Answer (score 0):

" $obj.animate({ top :'-= parseInt(0.5px)'+random }, 20, flutter);"